# Rails 6 - add a condition before allowing a user to create a new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I've the condition working in the controller, but would like to move the logic/condition into the model.

I've a simple form, inside the new method in the controller I'm checking if the user has already submitted, if so I don't allow him to create a new submission.
If the user has a previous submission I'm showing a flash message.

Now, I need to move the logic to the model. how can I call the function from the model?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your current working example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your own validator to the Model. Something on the lines of the example below.

You could create a Validator class that carries the specific checks you're looking for and assign it on the model with`validates_with` .

```rb
class GoodnessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.first_name == "Evil"
      record.errors.add :base, "This person is evil"
    end
  end
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with GoodnessValidator
end
```